# Why 2 NULL pointers do not evaluate to false?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, boolean

I have a relatively simple algorithm that walks an std::vector looking for two neighbouring tuples. Once the tuples left and right of the X value are found I can interpolate between them. Somehow this works:

```
  std::vector<LutTuple*>::iterator tuple_it;
  LutTuple* left = NULL;
  LutTuple* right = NULL;
  bool found = 0;

  // Only iterate as long as the points are not found
  for(tuple_it = lut.begin(); (tuple_it != lut.end() && !found); tuple_it++) {
    // If the tuple is less than r2 we found the first element
    if((*tuple_it)->r < r) {
        left = *tuple_it;
    }
    if ((*tuple_it)->r > r) {
        right = *tuple_it;
    }
    if(left && right) {
        found = 1;
    }
  }
```

while this:

```
  std::vector<LutTuple*>::iterator tuple_it;
  LutTuple* left = NULL;
  LutTuple* right = NULL;

  // Only iterate as long as the points are not found
  for(tuple_it = lut.begin(); tuple_it != lut.end() && !left && !right; tuple_it++) {
    // If the tuple is less than r2 we found the first element
    if((*tuple_it)->r < r) {
        left = *tuple_it;
    }
    if ((*tuple_it)->r > r) {
        right = *tuple_it;
    }
  }
```

does not. Why is that? I'd expect two NULL ptrs like this to evaluate to true together when negated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a logical issue.

In the first snippet you have (essentially) `!(left && right)`.

In the second snippet you have: `!left && !right`.

Those are not equivalent.

If you build the truth table, you will realize that `!(left && right)` is equivalent to `(!left || !right)`.

Answer (score 5):

The second loop will terminate as soon as either is found. Change the condition to:

```
tuple_it != lut.end() && !(left && right)
```

or

```
tuple_it != lut.end() && (!left || !right)
```

to continue until both are found.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd expect two NULL ptrs like this to evaluate to true together when
>   negated.

This does not make sense. Do not "negate" pointers and expect what they will evaluate to when forced into a boolean expression. Instead, I recommend to explicitly compare them to NULL.

Also, move your complex boolean expression for continuing the loop into a separate line, otherwise it becomes very hard to follow the code logically.

Comment: The standard conversion from pointer to boolean is well defined. The choice of whether to use that or an explicit comparison is purely aesthetic.

Comment: @Mike, my answer addresses readability, not correctness. I am sure that the code behaves "correctly" as it is written - it is just that it does not do what the author expects, so the problem is largely about making it more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: One could just as easily argue that the standard conversion is more readable and less error-prone; the choice is purely aesthetic, and your personal preference is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: I generally agree that "null is false" is sort of lame.  But it is the convention, and especially with shared pointers the operator overload keeps the code brief: http://hostilefork.com/2009/10/26/treating-non-booleans-as-logic/

Comment: @MikeSeymour It's not purely aesthetic.  The conversion confuses a lot of people.  Myself included, but judging from the number of errors I see with regards to things like using the return value of `stdchr`, apparently I'm not alone.

Comment: @JamesKanze: And I sometimes get confused by the double-negative of testing that something is not null; but not enough to post off-topic suggestions that people follow my aesthetic preferences instead of their own.